# Why does my TableViewCell doesn't show other data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I intended to display data from my Firestore Database into my app using the TableViewCell. It supposed to show the bookTitle, bookAuthor and bookSummary but the bookAuthor does not show up. Below is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.textLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookTitle
        cell.textLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookAuthor
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookSummary
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return books.count
    }
```

[image: UI Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting *the same* label to `bookAuthor` and `bookSummary` here:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookAuthor
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookSummary
```

So, it gets set to `bookAuthor`, and then immediately overwritten by `bookSummary`.

You could create/use another label for one of the fields, or concatenate the strings for this single label:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(books[indexPath.row].bookAuthor ?? "") - \(books[indexPath.row].bookSummary ?? "")"
```

Comment: See my updated answer. You can use `??` to provide a default answer. It'll be a good project to learn about "nil safety" in Swift as you continue.

Comment: I've tried the code and it works! Thank you so much. Sorry for asking, how to add a newline for the bookSummary? I've included `\n` but it has error.

Comment: I'm glad it answered your question. You can use the green checkmark to mark the answer as accepted and you can use the up arrow to upvote if you felt it was helpful.

Comment: In terms of `\n`, that seems beyond the scope of this question, especially since you haven't specified what the error is. Probably best to start a new question for that issue unless it's easily/quickly communicated here.

Comment: noted. I'll start new question for `\n`. thank you so much, really appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

As You had used textLabel and detailTextLabel: It's used for giving label and a subtitle. You can't use detailTextLabel twice. So its overriding your bookAuthor by bookSummary.

Please try to write like this:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookTitle
    cell.textLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row].bookAuthor + "\n" + books[indexPath.row].bookSummary
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried the code however there are errors saying "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'", "Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'", "Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'"

Comment: Then you can force unwrap it or you can use nil coalescing by providing default value.